# Registros de una tabla y buscarlos en otra Access

Tags: java, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inserto la imágen para que se vea correctamente.
Decir también que en la t1 pueden existir datos en la columna minutos que no son exactos por ejemplo Minuto 17 segundo 32 pero esto para mi es un registro erróneo y no debería de aparecer en la tabla t3. Esto no es un problema ya que no se cumplirá la condición t1.Hour=t2.Hour AND t1.Minute=t2.Minute, sólo como aclaración.

Comment: Muy buenas, bienvenid@. ¿Podrías poner un poco de código de cómo lo has intentando para que te podamos ayudar?

Comment: Gracias dddenis por responder he editado la entrada con el código que estoy probando.

Comment: Gracias Alan, por editar la entrada estoy viendo como funciona esta plataforma ;)

Comment: Esto creo que se puede hacer directamente en sql. Aclaraciones: " copiar el resto de columnas en una tercera tabla" 'Copiar'  significa insertar? Las tres tablas tienen la misma estructura? Conoces la estructura (columnas) de las tablas?

Comment: Hola Leonbloy, gracias por responder asi es, cuando digo copiar es insertar. La estructura no es la misma ya que la segunda tabla es creada por mi con sólo tres columnas de intervalos de tiempo a 10 min y es la correcta, por eso quiero comprobar si el registro de la tabla correcta coincide con el registro de la tabla 1 (donde se encuentran todos los datos) insertar todos los datos en una tercera tabla y si no existe que me inserte los datos (Fecha-hora-minutos)indicando "sin datos". Las columnas de la tabla son Fecha-Hora-Minutos con intervalos de 10 minutos de todo un año completo.

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que @leonbloy. Esto se puede realizar con un solo query, sin necesidad de más código que la ejecución de esa sentencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código asume que siempre hay la misma cantidad de registros en ambas tablas T1 y T2 (las llamo así porque no has dicho sus nombres). En caso que exista una fila en la primera tabla que no exista en la segunda pues tu código dejará de funcionar porque el segundo `ResultSet rs2` habrá avanzado una posición. Esto se puede ver de mejor manera en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
rs1: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
rs2: [ 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Según tu código, `rs1` en su primera posición debe tener el mismo valor que `rs2` en su primera posición. Para el ejemplo, esto es correcto. Sucede lo mismo en la segunda posición. En la tercera posición, los valores son diferentes por lo que el cursor de `rs2` debería mantenerse en la misma posición pero según tu algoritmo `rs2` igual avanzará generando inconsistencia de datos.

Puedes resolver esto a nivel de aplicación, pero es muy costoso:

1. Ejecutas dos queries, quizás con muchos datos.
2. Estás cargando esos datos para que viajen a través de la red.
3. Siempre vas a insertar en la tabla T3. Cada operación `INSERT` significa más acceso a la base de datos.

Cuando debas realizar funcionalidades que accedan a la red, por ejemplo operaciones contra la base de datos, debes minimizar las llamadas realizadas, así optimizas la velocidad de tu aplicación (por mucho, aunque no parezca en un inicio). Este problema puede ser resuelto con un solo script, de la siguiente forma:

```sql
INSERT INTO T3 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT
    T2.col1,
    T2.col2,
    T2.col3,
    Nz(T1.col4, 'sin datos'),
    Nz(T1.col5, 'sin datos)
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.col1 = T2.col1
    AND T1.col2 = T2.col2
    AND T1.col3 = T2.col3
```

Explicación del query:

- `INSERT INTO T3 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) SELECT`: indicas que se insertarán todos los resultados de la consulta obtenida en la sentencia `SELECT`. Se indican las columnas de la tabla T3 donde se insertarán los datos (colocar los nombres reales de las columnas).
- `Nz(T1.col4, 'sin datos')`: `Nz` es una función SQL que recibe dos parámetros, el valor a evaluar y el valor por defecto. Si el valor a evaluar (primer parámetro) es nulo, entonces se devuelve el valor por defecto (segundo parámetro). Según explicas, se debe utilizar el dato de T2 para insertar, de lo contrario se debe registrar `'sin datos'`.
- `FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON ...`: Un [`LEFT JOIN`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join#De_tabla_izquierda_.28LEFT_OUTER_JOIN_o_LEFT_JOIN.29) permite hacer una unión de la tabla de la izquierda con la tabla de la derecha, devolviendo siempre **todos los resultados** de la tabla izquierda a pesar que no se encuentre una igualdad con la tabla derecha. Para aquellos registros donde no hubo igualdad, los resultados de la tabla derecha devuelven `NULL`, por ello el uso de `Nz` al obtener los datos.

Luego de armar este query, tu código Java se reduce a la ejecución de 1 solo query, reduciendo el acceso de red y optimizando el uso de la base de datos.

Comment: COALESCE no existe en Access debes utilizar la funcion Nz. De la forma Nz(T2.col4, 'sin datos')

Comment: Gracias @Ipman1971 respuesta editada

Comment: Gracias Luiggi por tu tiempo y dedicación y también a @lpman1971 por tu aclaración, de momento no me ha funcionado con esta query he editado la entrada para aclarar un poco más el problema. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: @F.Sola según leo entonces no es mezclar T1 con T2 sino al revés: T2 con T1. La solución sería la misma pero cambiando el orden de las tablas. Acabo de actualizar la respuesta para reflejar el cambio de orden en el query. La idea sigue siendo la misma puesto que los valores que predominarán serán los de T2 y se agregarán los valores de T1 que hagan match con los de T2.

Comment: Luiggi me ha funcionado correctamente la query de momento estoy haciendo pruebas sólo con SELECT para controlar los cambios de hora que tenemos, que son 2 y suelen ser en Marzo y Octubre muchas gracias por tu ayuda.